# Поиск по сайту: не ищутся русские слова

Tags: кодировка, php

Здравствуйте, ребят. Помогите, пожалуйста, с поиском. Из за того, что с кодировкой проблемы у меня не ищет русские слова, то есть в поисковой запрос, пишешь русские слова, но из за кодировки он проверяет фиг знает какими символами, а ели английские пишешь, то он находит.

```
<?

function search($words) {
    $words = htmlspecialchars($words);
    if ($words == "") return false;
    $query_search = "";

    $arraywords = explode(" ", $words);
    foreach($arraywords as $key => $value){
        if (isset($arraywords[$key -1]))
            $query_search .= ' OR ';
        $query_search .= '`title` LIKE "%'.$value.'%" OR `name` LIKE "%'.$value.'%"';

    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM services WHERE $query_search";

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","...","...","...");
    $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");
    $mysqli->close();
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result_set ->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[$i] = $row;
        $i++;
    }
    return $results;
}
if (isset($_POST['bsearch'])) { 
        $words = $_POST['words'];
        $results = search($words);
        print_r($results);

}
?>
```

Comment: А вас одна функция делает кучу действий. Какие проблемы у вас с кодировкой?

Comment: я обычно к бд по другому подключаюсь, и там чтобы кодировка нормальная была я прописываю

    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

и она нормальной бывает потом,
а в этом случае я к бд подключаюсь вот так:

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","...","...","...");
    $result_set = $mysqli->query($query);

но в этом слуаче почему то
    mysql_query("SET NAMES UTF8");

не работает.
что делать вот мне?

Comment: из за кодировки он и найти не может из БД нужную мне информацию, а когда ищешь что то на латинском языке он находит, только опять же руский язык иероглифами выводит

Answer (score 2):

Я не хочу комментировать то, что у Вас происходит) 
Но все мы с чего то начинали. 
Поэтому: а) SET NAMES указывает в какой кодироваке работать по закрытия подключения.
т.е. Вы сначала данные получаете, а только потом говорите в какой кодировке хотите их получить.

б) Если используете mysqli, то его и используйте

```
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES UTF8");
$result_set = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: отдуши просто, спасибо тебе друг огромнейшее))

Answer (score 1):

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

1 строчка и запоминается легко